# Adding doc to firebase using react native and encountering many errors with promises/async storage

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

So im trying to make a todo list app and making the fucntion to add a doc to firebase.  However, when i do that expo says the async storage has been deprecated and that there is a unhandled promise rejection

my code in my app:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {useState} from "react"
import { SafeAreaView, Text, View, Button, TouchableOpacity, Modal, StyleSheet,Pressable, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { collection, doc, setDoc, query, getDocs, onSnapshot, addDoc, orderBy, limit, Timestamp, where} from "firebase/firestore"; 
import {db} from "../firebase"
import { signPlsOut } from '../firebase';
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
export  const Dashboard = () => {
  const {uid, photoURL, displayName} = auth.currentUser;
  const projectsref =  collection(db, "projects");
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  async function handleAddTask () {
    try {
      await addDoc(projectsref, {
        title: title,
        desc: desc,
        createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        uid: uid,
      }) 
      setTitle("")
      setDesc("")
      setModalVisible(false)
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
      // ADD THIS THROW error
      throw error;
    }
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
     <View style={{
       margin: 20
     }}>
        <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Add task:</Text>
            <View style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
              <TextInput placeholder='title' value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}></TextInput>
              <TextInput placeholder='description' value={desc} onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}></TextInput>
            </View>
            <Button title='submit todo' onPress={handleAddTask}></Button>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Cancel</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
       <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "500"}}>Welcome,</Text>
       <Text style={{fontSize: 27, fontWeight: "700"}}>{auth.currentUser.email}</Text>
      <View style={{marginTop: 30}}>
       <Text style={{fontSize: 40, fontWeight: "700", color: "#0404"}}>Create Task</Text>
       <TouchableOpacity>
         <View style={{
           backgroundColor: "orange",
           borderRadius: "20px"
         }}>
         <Pressable
        style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOpen]}
        onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
      >
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Add task</Text>
      </Pressable>
         </View>
       </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
       <Button title="signout" onPress={signPlsOut}></Button>
     </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

error:
async sotrage has been extracted and will be removed in a future release, in addition to the unhandled promise rejection error

Comment: There are a number of things to consider here. What Expo SDK version are you using, what version of react-native are you using (package.json)? I just updated to expo SDK version 44 and react-native 64.3 and in that, i received the deprecation notice about async storage as well and was able top figure that out. I am happy to answer with what i did to fix that error, but it might not answer your entire/greater question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to actually add the doc to firebase? Some more context would be helpful in what you're trying to do. Is you code above completely unsucessful and you are getting errors? Or are you simply trying to clear errors.

If you are just trying to get rid of the unhandled promise rejection. I ran into a similar error and I found where in the Firebase app node_module where the call out was being for async storage. For me to get rid of a similar error i did two steps:

First, i installed the new react native async storage module:

`npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`

Next, i had to update firebase app module, in the following file, to point to the appropriate API within my expo app to point to this new react native async storage module.

./node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.rn.cjs.js

I had to adjust this bit of code in this file:

```
var AsyncStorage = require('@react-native-async-storage/async-storage').AsyncStorage;
firebase.INTERNAL.extendNamespace({
    INTERNAL: {
        reactNative: {
            AsyncStorage: AsyncStorage
        }
    }
});
```

The above code previously called to "react" i believe, i just needed to update it to specifically call to "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage". And this solved my problem.